# Windows Phone Dev Center - Replace button isn't there for updating

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-store

I'm trying to update my Windows Phone app, which I've done before, using the [guidance for app management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj631569%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), but the Replace button which appears in the guide [isn't present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqJUK.png) in my Dev Center. (imgur link because I can't post images, sorry :) )

Instead I've got some ellipses which don't do anything when clicked. I don't want to re-enter all the app information and screenshots, and I know that doing Replace lets you keep all the entered data. I just wonder why this option isn't showing for me?

I'm targetting the same OS (8.0) as my last version, but now 8.1 is out, is that affecting it? I added a new capability to the app, but that can't be hiding the Replace button because it wouldn't know until I uploaded.

Hope someone can shed some light for me :)

Comment: Try a different browser.

Comment: Is your developer account up-to-date?  It expires once a year...

Comment: Did you select the radio button and then check if update button appears?

Comment: @ErtayShashko Tried it in IE11 and the button appeared! Thank you! This must have been a Firefox+Silverlight issue. Cheers :)

Comment: No, it's not because of Silverlight. The Silverlight plug-in is there and it's working fine. The issue is that the `div` that hosts the Silverlight plug-in has a `width` of `0`, only in Firefox. If you use FireBug to give it a 'width' of say, `100`, the *replace* button will appear.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Firefox. There are two solutions:

1) Use IE. It works in IE.

2) Just click the ellipsis. This worked fine for me.